# How to take active parts with EPartService?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to take active parts by using EPartService. Can I use EPartService for this?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'take active parts'?

Comment: I want to learn which parts are active. Then I will close these active parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the active part in something like a command handler you can inject it as a parameter:

```
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart activePart)
{
  ... handler code
}
```

If you want a list of all currently displayed parts you can use the  `EPartService`. Something like:

```
@Inject
MApplication app;

@Inject
EPartService partService;

// Find all the `MPart` objects in the current presentation

Collection<MPart> parts = partService.getParts();

// Filter the list to include just the parts that are current being displayed (rendered)

parts = parts.stream().filter(MPart::isToBeRendered).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: This code requires Java 8

Comment: I want to learn all closable and opened parts in window. I think this "activePart" represent only a activePart. Is the code part provide this?

Comment: Well those are not 'active'. I have added code to find all the currently displayed (rendered) parts